# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable - I have been looking into this for hours now and i can not understand why it is spitting out this error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to nest multiple lists in a single 'master' list, when ever i go through the lists to add the items in other lists to the master in order, so i can create a save file using pickle in another piece of code (not related to this problem at all),

I have not been able to find an alternative

```
a = [123456789]
b = [2, 6, "CF"]
c=["Helo", 4567]
d=[3,5,6,4,4,3,5]
e=["345sadf fg", 48736541546]
master = []
for i in range(5):
    master.append([])
#insert items into list - Format = homework, tnotes, pnotes, camau, studentname
for a in range(len(a)):
    master[0].append(a[a])
for b in range(len(b)):
    master[1].append(b[b])
for c in range(len(c)):
    master[2].append(c[c])
for d in range(len(d)):
    master[3].append(d[d])
for e in range(len(e)):
    master[4].append(e[e])
print(str(master))

I would expect:
[[123456789],
 [2,6, "CF"],
 ["Helo",4657],
 [3,5,6,4,4,3,5],
 ["345sadf fg",48736541546]]
```

Comment: what line triggers the error? there are many things wrong with the code, for example `for a in range(len(a))` is a big no no, change your variable names to `for i in range(lange(a))`

Comment: what do you think `a[a]` should do?

Comment: bottom line, you can just do, `list_of_list = [a, b, c, d ,e]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` in `for a in range(len(a)):` shadows the name `a = [123456789]` from outer scope. So, when you do `master[0].append(a[a])`, *both* `a`s refer to the *integer* `a` you got from `range`. The same thing happens in *all* the other loops.

So, `a[a]` (side note: this is highly confusing to begin with because it's unclear what `a` this refers to; Python establishes strict rules concerning this) attempts to index the `int`eger `a` with the index `a`, which makes no sense because "`int` objects are not subscriptable", so you get an error.

You should name the index variables of your loops differently.